# Different time formats in computing?

Tags: datetime, time

I'm putting together a function where I can easily convert between standard time formats found in computing.

Here's a few off of the top of my head:

- Unix time (the number of seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970)
- Unix time in JavaScript (the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970)
- MySQL DATETIME (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

What are some other standard formats? Is there a list of this anywhere online?

Answer (score 1):

The Common Lisp epoch, i.e. numbers of seconds since begins at 1900-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
Also, plain integers are quite common: as in `2012-07-10 -> 20120710U` or even binary encoded decimals (on 64bit systems at least): `2012-07-12 -> 0x0200010200070102ULL`.

Advantage of the latter solutions is obviously that you can really easy go back and forth between printed and internal representation, and relations (`<`, `>`, `==`) work too.  Also you would be able to say something like `2012-06-00` or `2012-00-01` (as in omitting the day-of-month or month respectively).

Disadvantage is you need a bit more magic when you want to, say, add 1 day.  On the other hand it's possible to define add-1-month in a meaningful way, something you couldn't do with an epoch representation.

**Edit**
Came up with some more:

- if you're doing calendar agnostic calculations, you'd probably resort to julian dates 2451545 is roughly 2000-01-01 12:00:00 UTC
- Matlab uses fractional days since 0000-01-01 in a proleptic gregorian calendar

Well diving into the list of single software specific date representations you could probably fill a whole book.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 - the ISO date format.

However, most languages have standard utilities for this stuff already... are you sure you're not doing this unnecessarily?